# Render a pair of randomly chosen objects (with certain property unmatched) as play cards in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm making a little game where the user guesses which of the two foods has the most calories. I scraped data on 400+ food items and imported in my component.

I want to make sure that both randomly selected food items do not have the same number of calories. I put a while loop in componentDidMount to check if it's true. If true, it will setState to another randomly selected food – repeat until they're no longer the same number.

For now, I have my while loop's condition set to '!==' for testing. This will be changed to '===' after I know it works the other way. The problem I'm having is that in my console, the foods will always be the same objects because setState isn't working for some reason.

```
import Foods from "../foods.json";

class Game extends Component {
  state = {
    firstFood: Foods[Math.floor(Math.random() * Foods.length)],
    secondFood: Foods[Math.floor(Math.random() * Foods.length)],
    mostCalories: "placeholder"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    while (
      // to check that the two foods' calories are not the same

      this.state.firstFood.attributes.calories !==
      this.state.secondFood.attributes.calories
    ) {
      console.log(this.state.firstFood.attributes.calories);
      console.log(this.state.secondFood.attributes.calories);
      debugger;
      // an infinite loop because the below setState function doesn't run properly

      this.setState({
        firstFood: Foods[Math.floor(Math.random() * Foods.length)]
      });
    }
  }
```

Another issue I'm facing is that in my debugger, when I try to manually enter `Foods[Math.floor(Math.random() * Foods.length)]`, I get a "Food is not defined" although it works in the state initialization. However, when I enter `_foods_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__` in console from autofill, I have all of my data there so this works (replaced the word "Foods"):

```
_foods_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__[Math.floor(Math.random() * _foods_json__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_1__.length)]
```

I can't use that line of code in React, though.

http://www.giphy.com/gifs/UqwKkdF2ok2hlTwlLB

Comment: Use `componentDidUpdate` or `getDerivedStateFromProps` when you want to update the state when props change. Or, **just do the computations inside the render function**.

Comment: @YevgenGorbunkov I think your answer solves it. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest slightly different approach for generating a pair of pseudo-random items, that may not save you CPU cycles, but will certainly avoid loops that led you to your current position.

So, the idea is rather simple:

- you pick first random item
- then you filter out the items with the same nutritional value
- you pick another random item from remaining ones

```
pickTwo = arr => {
          const firstItem = arr[0|Math.random()*arr.length],
                filteredArr = arr.filter(({value}) => firstItem.value != value),
                secondItem = filteredArr[0|Math.random()*filteredArr.length]
          return [firstItem, secondItem]
        }
```

You may find the demo of that concept below:

```js
//dependencies
const { useState, useEffect } = React,
      { render } = ReactDOM
//sample data set
const data = [{name:'BBQ Ranch Burger',value:350},{name:'Big Mac',value:540},{name:'Double Cheesburger',value:440},{name:'Bacon Cheddar McChicken',value:540},{name:'Chicken McNuggets (10 piece)',value:440},{name:'Bacon Biscuit',value:350}]

//food card component
const FoodCard = ({name,value}) => (
  <div style={{width:100,height:150,display:'table-cell', border:'1px solid black',verticalAlign:'middle',textAlign:'center'}}>{name}<br/>(calories: {value})</div>
)
//game board component
const GameBoard = () => {
  //store foods within local state
  const [foods,setFoods] = useState([]),
        //describe thw way of picking two pseudo-random items
        pickTwo = arr => {
          const firstItem = arr[0|Math.random()*arr.length],
                filteredArr = arr.filter(({value}) => firstItem.value != value),
                secondItem = filteredArr[0|Math.random()*filteredArr.length]
          return [firstItem, secondItem]
        }
  //pick two cards on initial render      
  useEffect(() => setFoods(pickTwo(data)),[])
  //return component
  return (
    <div>
      <FoodCard {...foods[0]} />
      <FoodCard {...foods[1]} />
      <button onClick={() => setFoods(pickTwo(data))}>reset</button>
    </div>
  )
}

render(
  <GameBoard />,
  document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.12.0/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.11.0/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script><div id="root"></div>
```

Comment: Amazing. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

The reason your loop will run endlessly is that, when you call `setState` the state is not actually immediately updated, there is a lag on it, which has to do with the React component lifecycle.

So instead of calling the setState in the loop. Declare a local variable, update the variable in the loop and when the loop is done, then set the state.

```js
  componentDidMount() {
    let myFood = this.state.firstFood
    while (
      // to check that the two foods' calories are not the same
      myFood.attributes.calories !==
      this.state.secondFood.attributes.calories
    ) {
       myFood = Foods[Math.floor(Math.random() * Foods.length)]
    }

    this.setState({
      firstFood: myFood
    });
  }
```

I did not test this in detail but that should give you the idea.

Answer (score 1):

State is not just some variable that you set whenever you want. It is reactive. It causes re-renders. You should pick two foods you want to have, make sure they don't have the same calories and only then do you `setState` them

There is no reason to `setState` on `componentDidMount`, your logic belongs in `constructor`

```
const _pickFoods = (allFoods) => {
  const firstFood = allFoods[Math.floor(Math.random() * allFoods.length)]
  let secondFood
  do {
    secondFood = allFoods[Math.floor(Math.random() * allFoods.length)]
  } while (firstFood.attributes.calories !== secondFood.attributes.calories)
  return { firstFood, secondFood }
}

class Game  extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
    const { firstFood, secondFood } = _pickFoods(Foods)
    this.state = {
      firstFood,
      secondFood
    }
  }
  ...
}
```

That is if you want this while logic in your foods. It will loop forever if your Foods array consists of unviable foods only. Try this better alternative

```
const _pickFoods = (allFoods) => {
  const firstFood = allFoods[Math.floor(Math.random() * allFoods.length)]
  const possibleSecondFoods = allFoods.filter(food => food !== firstFood && food.attributes.calories !== firstFood.attributes.calories)
  const secondFood = possibleSecondFoods[Math.floor(Math.random() * possibleSecondFoods.length)]
  return secondFood
}
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this:

```
    import Foods from "../foods.json";

class Game extends Component {
  state = {
    firstFood: Foods[Math.floor(Math.random() * Foods.length)],
    secondFood: Foods[Math.floor(Math.random() * Foods.length)],
    mostCalories: "placeholder"
  };

  componentDidMount() {
    setTimeout( () => {
     while (
       // to check that the two foods' calories are not the same

       this.state.firstFood.attributes.calories !==
       this.state.secondFood.attributes.calories
     ) {
      console.log(this.state.firstFood.attributes.calories);
       console.log(this.state.secondFood.attributes.calories);
       debugger;
       // an infinite loop because the below setState function doesn't run properly

       this.setState({
         firstFood: Foods[Math.floor(Math.random() * Foods.length)]
       });
     }
    },2000)
  }
```

I think it is because the data is not ready yet.

Comment: This is bad practice at many levels. First, it will render two unviable foods, let user interact with component, and, after 2 seconds have passed, it will try to change secondFood. Second, it will keep re-rendering until it finds proper food, or forever if there is no proper second food. Third, it will run `while` block before the state is even updated..